# How to construct specific Java regexp

Tags: java, regex

I need to check a login name. It has to (it's political, not technical decision) have:

1. from 5 to 30 characters;
2. characters must be from group `[a-zA-Z0-9*]`;
3. at least one character must be number;
4. it's not possible to have all characters just from numbers if login name has 5 characters but if it has 6 or more character, it can be constructed just from numbers.

I have regexp `(?=[a-zA-Z0-9*]*[0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9*]{5,30}` wich works for points 1-3, but can't imagine how to include check for point 4.

Comment: If you're going to be doing this in just Java, why not just use an if / else to break this into 2 regexes based on a count of characters?  It's technically possible and I'm trying to whip it up now...

Comment: You could add a look-behing like `(?![0-9]{5}$)`

Comment: @SebastianProske that would not allow sequences of 5 digits at the end but what if the password is something like `a12345`?

Comment: @Thomas You should add the lookbehind in front (like the other one) and it will allow login names like `a12345`, see https://regex101.com/r/vY1vD7/1

Comment: @SebastianProske looks like this works, thanks :) i'm checking it [here](http://example.com)

Comment: @Thomas as i wrote in point 3 and 4, `a12345` is correct login

Answer (score 1):

Use regex with [negative look ahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

```
(?!\d{5}$)(?=[a-zA-Z\d*]*\d)[a-zA-Z\d*]{5,30}
```

---

[Regex explanation here.](https://regex101.com/r/sE3mK3/2)

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Answer (score 1):

It is always tempting to validate all aspects of a string using a single, pretty complicated regular expression. But keep in mind that this thing might be hard to extend, maintain in the future.

Meaning: depending on the rate of "changes" to your validation rules, there might be better designs. For example, one could envision something like:

```
interface NameValidator {
    isValid(String name) throws InvalidNameException;
}

class LengthValidator implements NameValidator ...
class XyzValidator implements NameValidator ...

class NameValidation {
   private final List validators = Arrays.toList(new LengthValidator(), ...

   void isValid(String name) {
      run all validators ...
```

This way, adding / changing one of your validation rules ... becomes much more straight forward ... than tampering a single regular expression, potentially breaking some other part of it.

Beyond that, you can even build different rule set; by combining different instances of NameValidation implementers; whilst avoiding code duplication .

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, you don’t have to do it with a single regex.  Even if that’s possible, it will be obnoxiously complex and difficult for others to understand.

The simplest approach is the best:

```
boolean passwordValid = password.matches("[a-zA-Z0-9*]{5,30}")
    && password.matches(".*[0-9].*")
    && !password.matches("[0-9]{5}");
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to propose a different approach: don't use a regex but check each character and collect password properties. That way you are able to implement more complex requirements later on, e.g. "it must have 3 out of 4".

Example:

```
String pw = "1a!cde";

Set<PwProperty> passwordProperties = new HashSet<>();
for( char c : pw.toCharArray() ) {
  if( isDigit( c ) ) { 
    passwordProperties.add( PwProperty.DIGIT ); 
  }
  else if ( isSpecialChar( c ) ) { 
    passwordProperties.add( PwProperty.SPECIAL); 
  }
  else if( isUpperCase( c ) ) {
    passwordProperties.add( PwProperty.UPPER_CASE); 
  }
  else if( isLowerCase( c ) ) {
    passwordProperties.add( PwProperty.LOWER_CASE); 
  }
  else {
    passwordProperties.add( PwProperty.UNKNOWN ); 
  }
}
```

Then you could check that like this (pseudo code):

```
if( !pw.length() in range ) {
   display "password too short" or "password too long"
}

if( passwordProperties.contains( PwProperty.UNKNOWN ) {
  display "unsupported characters used"
}

Set<PwProperty> setOf4 = { DIGIT, SPECIAL, LOWER_CASE, UPPER_CASE }
if( intersection( passwordProperties, setOf4 ).size() < 3 ) {
  display "use at least 3 out of 4"
}

if( !passwordProperties.contains( DIGIT ) ) {
  display "must contain digits"
}

display "password strength" being intersection( passwordProperties, setOfGoodProperties ).size()

etc.
```

This can then be expanded e.g. with properties like `DIGIT_SEQUENCE` which might be unwanted etc.

The main advantage is that you have more detailed information on the password rather than "it matches a certain regex or not" and you can use that information to guide the user.

Comment: there should be problem in case you need to use regex in config file

Comment: @LadislavDANKO that's true and that might be a reason not to use that approach. However, this is meant to provide more flexilibity expecially in guiding the user and still can be implemented in a way that allows for configuration via a text file.